# How to receive fix message from a server using QuickFix/J Engine?

Tags: java, quickfixj

I am a newbie to use `quickfixj`. I'm trying to prepare a client to receive message connecting  with an IP and port. After reading QFJ documentation/support, I can't get any idea. Is there a perfect way to receive message from the server using quick fix/J? The below class implemented with Connector interface.

```
SocketInitiator socketInitiator = new SocketInitiator(application,
                fileStoreFactory, sessionSettings, logFactory,
                messageFactory);
SessionID sessionId = socketInitiator.getSessions().get(0);

socketInitiator.start();    
@Override
public void start() throws ConfigError, RuntimeError{
Logon logon = new Logon();
    Header header = logon.getHeader();
    header.setField(new BeginString("FIX.4.2"));        //   "FIXT.1.1"
    logon.setField(new SenderSubID("pro"));
    logon.setField(new RawData("pro"));
    logon.setField(new SenderCompID("pro"));
    logon.setField(new TargetCompID("TRAD"));
    logon.set(new HeartBtInt(30));
    logon.set(new ResetSeqNumFlag(true));
    boolean sent = Session.sendToTarget(logon, sessionId);
    System.out.println("Logon Message Sent : " + sent);
 }
```

Comment: Yes. Read the documentation and follow the example code.

Comment: @vikingsteve Do you want to say something similar to RTFM ?

Comment: for the viewers who downrates question..If you don't wish to answer down rating the question is the only solution you got?

Comment: Please show some more effort before you post a question. What examples did you look at (show short code or link)? What didn't you understand?

Comment: @vikingsteve ok now you have said what flavours to be added. Before giving proper info down rating not seems wise

Comment: Now at least you've shown some example code, which you didn't have before, so I've removed my downvote.

Comment: @vikingsteve welcome... any suggestions regarding solution for my question ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you've provided is not the recommended way of using QuickFIX/j.

I don't know why you'd override `start()`, and you certainly should not be creating and explicitly sending `Logon` messages (or any other kind of admin message).  If you create and configure your app in the recommended way, the engine will automagically create and send the `Logon` message for you.

Before proceeding further, you really need to look at the QF/j example applications and review the manual.